# Blank console when exiting X

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, console, nvidia

I'm running Linux Mint 17.1, but this probably applies to most distros anyway.

I just installed LM cleanly from a bootable USB (which is fine - I checked) and I need to install the appropriate drivers from NVIDIA (which I can't do), which requires the X server to be closed. I try `sudo /etc/init.d/mdm stop`, and that takes me to a fully functional terminal - except from one thing. The entire screen is **black**, no text. Commands work fine, however.

Any pointers as to how I can fix this problem?

`lshw -C display` output:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:ce000000-cfffffff ioport:dc00(size=128) memory:feb00000-feb7ffff
```

**Edit: have now installed the NVIDIA drivers - they work, but still no terminal.**

Comment: What happens when you press Ctrl + Alt + F3?  As a hunch your Terminal is Restarting on Screen F1, which is the Bootsplash/Plymouth Terminal...

Comment: @eyoung100 Nothing - the only functional terminal is F8 - the MDM terminal.

Comment: And a Reboot? What happens then?

Comment: @eyoung100 Already tried that - no joy.

Comment: How did you Install the NVIDIA Drivers?

Comment: @eyoung100 That's the point - I haven't.

Comment: Post the output of `lshw -C display`

Comment: @eyoung100 http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Y7L5MVr6

Comment: Edit your Question to include the output.

Comment: @eyoung100 Done.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to use ssh? I'd ssh into the box to do something like install a graphics driver.

Answer (score 1):

Try dropping your system into single-user mode

To do this (I'm going to assume you're using GRUB, instructions are similar for other bootloaders), hold shift during bootup.  Select the default entry and modify it.  Append `single` to the end of the boot options

When the system boots up, it should drop you into a fully functional terminal

Alternatively, if this does not work, boot into a live environment and chroot into your system

Lastly, make sure you use the `nomodeset` boot flag.  This is known to cause issues with some graphics drivers

Comment: I need a permanent fix - this doesn't look like one.

Comment: This will get you into a terminal - which you can then use to fix your graphics drivers